# Cannot use GPU in CPU-only Caffe: check mode

Tags: python, installation, caffe

I am using a legacy set up of caffe which is running on CPU.

I switched one line of code from:

```
caffe.set_mode_cpu()
```

to:

```
caffe.set_mode_gpu()
```

but I get the error:

```
Cannot use GPU in CPU-only Caffe: check mode.
```

I checked the Makefile.config and the relevant setting was:

```
#CPU-only switch (uncomment to build without GPU support)
CPU_only := 1
```

I assume 1 is True so I changed to

```
CPU_only := 0
```

but it did not help.

Any clues?

Comment: Comment the line to build with GPU: `#CPU_only := 1`

Comment: Have you recompiled caffe after you changed CPU_only to 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change:

```
#CPU-only switch (uncomment to build without GPU support)
CPU_only := 1
```

to this:

```
#CPU-only switch (uncomment to build without GPU support)
#CPU_only := 1
```

and rebuild.